# Keep only alphabetic characters and numbers if text have corrupted characters?

Tags: r, regex

I have a file with some corrupted characters and I want to clean it and keep only alphabetic characters and numbers. The data looks like this:

```
data <- c("120 RED[¹", "121 ªÚêÝk College", "[²¯x¬ Street", "Sky ªÚêÝk")
```

the desired output is:

```
clean_data <- c("120 RED","121 College", "Street","Sky")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This would replace all except letters, numbers, & blank space with "":

```
gsub("([^A-Za-z0-9 ])+", "", x = data)

[1] "120 RED"       "121 k College" "x Street"      "Sky k"
```

I'm afraid it'll still leave the random k, x, and k in there, as those were normal letters surrounded by corrupted ones.

Comment: There are unwanted characters though

Comment: @ Z.Lin thanks exactly what I wanted.